# How to install exif extension on php in linux system

Tags: php, linux, exif

I want to upload images.but program have a fatal error:undefined function exif_read_data(),I don't know how to install exif extension in php on linux system.Hope the junior help me.Thank you very much.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl   OR switch it to yum, if you use that.  Good practice to do an update before that as well.